# Build pyodide on windows WSL2

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pyodide

Trying to build pyodide on windows WSL2. I have already created a conda environment with the required python version. But I'm still constantly getting the following error:

> wasm-ld: error: unknown argument: --sysroot=/
> em++: error: '/home/xxx/LearningCenter/pyodide/emsdk/emsdk/upstream/bin/wasm-ld -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/msgpack/_cmsgpack.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so --whole-archive --sysroot=/ -L/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/pyodide-dev/lib -L/home/xxx/miniconda3/envs/pyodide-dev/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/msgpack/_cmsgpack.o -L/home/xxx/LearningCenter/pyodide/emsdk/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/pic --no-whole-archive -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr --lto-legacy-pass-manager --allow-undefined --import-memory --strip-debug --export-all --no-gc-sections --experimental-pic -shared' failed (1)

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem ?